# Create, append and insert data to a file on php

Tags: php, html

I have a plan to make a very very simple publishing page for my new site. It will be created by html files.

Like a post publish page of wordpress, there will be input fields like "Title", "Content" and some extra fields for entering meta data of the page. When i hit the publish button, the script will create a file like "title.html" and the content will consist of some other template files and the data sent from the publish page. The basic code for publish page i have created is below;

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
<table><tr><td>Title:</td><td><input type="text" name="title" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Content to be added</td><td><textarea required="required" name="content"style="width: 600px; height: 138px;"/></textarea></td></tr></table>
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm &raquo;" />
</form>
```

and the post.php is like that;

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">  

<?php 

$content = $_POST['content'];
$title = $_POST['title'];       

$my_file1 = 'file1.html';
$handle = fopen($my_file1, 'r');
$data1 = fread($handle,filesize($my_file1));

$my_file2 = 'file2.html';
$handle = fopen($my_file2, 'r');
$data2 = fread($handle,filesize($my_file2));

$data3 = $data1.$content.$data2;

$my_file3 = $title;
$handle = fopen($my_file3, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file3);
fwrite($handle, $data3);

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Content of file1.html;

```
<html>
<head>
<codes>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
```

Content of file2.html;

```
</div>
<codes>
</body>
</html>
```

And the created file $title.html is like that;

```
<html>
<head>
<codes>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">$content</div>
<codes>
</body>
</html>
```

I wonder if managing this with one file (only file1.html not with file2.html) possible. I mean the script will read the content of file1.html, find the id=content and place the $content between this tags. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Edit:

As I found the solution by the help of Andrey B. I wanted to post it here;

```
<?php 

$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$intro = $_POST['intro'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$file = $_POST['file']; 


$my_file1 = 'post2.html';
$handle = fopen($my_file1, 'r');
$data1 = fread($handle,filesize($my_file1));

$data3 = sprintf($data1, $title, $description, $keywords, $intro, $content);

$my_file3 = $file;
$handle = fopen($my_file3, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file3);
fwrite($handle, $data3);

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$template = "<div>%s</div>";
$data = 'Hi, World!';
$text = sprintf($template, $data); # <div>Hi, World!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick respond. It worked very well.

Comment: Hello again, while the script is working fine, i wonder if there is a way to create file on another directory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achive it using require_once:

```
<?php require_once("file1.php") ?>

<?php echo $content ?>

<?php require_once("file2.php"); ?>
```

Is very common to use it this way to create your layout in mulple partial files.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.require-once.php

You can also use include, but I recommend you to better use require_once as best practice.

Comment: TS needs only in one file, not two

Comment: I think he wants to create a layout, so using require_once is the solution